# Коннектор php к openAPI Тинькофф Инвестиции

Tags: php, openapi

пытаюсь написать простой код на php для получения данных с сервера Тинькофф, на сайте компании https://tinkoffcreditsystems.github.io/invest-openapi/auth/ приведён пример кода на JAVA (наверное)

```
Authorization: Bearer {TOKEN}
```

Пример:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

const (
    token   = "just_place_token_here"
    timeout = time.Second * 3
    url     = "https://api-invest.tinkoff.ru/openapi/sandbox/sandbox/register"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: timeout,
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Can't create register http request: %s", err)
    }

    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+token)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Can't send register request: %s", err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        log.Fatalf("Register, bad response code '%s' from '%s'", resp.Status, url)
    }

    respBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Can't read register response: %s", err)
    }

    type Register struct {
        TrackingID string `json:"trackingId"`
        Status     string `json:"status"`
    }

    var regResp Register
    err = json.Unmarshal(respBody, &regResp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Can't unmarshal register response: '%s' \nwith error: %s", string(respBody), err)
    }

    if strings.ToUpper(regResp.Status) != "OK" {
        log.Fatalf("Register failed, trackingId: '%s'", regResp.TrackingID)
    }

    fmt.Println("Register succeed")
}
```

Хочу получить данные биржевых котировок и записать в sql таблицу для дальнейшего анализа и вывода данных. К сожалению с java не особо знаком, поэтому сложно разобраться самостоятельно, да и конекторы,кроме как к mySQL никогда не писал. Прошу помочь переделать код в php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это не Java, а Go. Да и весь пример сводится к тому, как выполнить произвольный запрос с указанием заголовка Authorization..

На php, с guzzle можно было бы например так:

```
$token = 'ваш_токен';

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://api-invest.tinkoff.ru/openapi',
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => "Bearer $token"
    ]
]);

$stocks = $client->get('market/stocks'); // запрос акций через rest api
```

Но на php давно не пишу, да и учетной записи в "Тиньков-инвестиции" у меня нет, что бы проверить - все исключительно по описанию указанному в них в [документации](https://tinkoffcreditsystems.github.io/invest-openapi/swagger-ui/#/market/get_market_stocks).

Другой вариант - не заморачиваться с этим, и просто воспользоваться [уже готовой библиотекой для php](https://github.com/jamesRUS52/tinkoff-invest), которая указана в [описании к официальному репозиторию OpenApi Тиньков-Инвестиции](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/invest-openapi)